# Finding the null space of a matrix using python

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

i am trying to find the null space of a matrix using python and sympy and i don't understand why `.nullspace()` doesn't work? What is my mistake? Is there another better python module for linear algebra?

If i print matrix x it is what i expect so i think the problem lies in the `.nullspace()` command or something with the data type of the matrix maybe?

```
import sympy as sp

def ranking(A,m=0.1):
   A = sp.Matrix(A)
   shape = sp.shape(A)
   n = shape[0]
   S = []

   for i in range(n):
      S.append([])
      for j in range(n):
         S[i].append(1/n)

   S = sp.Matrix(S)
   google = (1-m)*A + m*S
   x = sp.Matrix(google-sp.eye(n))

   return x.nullspace()
   
A = [[0  , 0  , 1/2, 1  ],
     [1/3, 0  , 0  , 0  ],
     [1/3, 1/2, 0  , 0  ],
     [1/3, 1/2, 1/2, 0  ]]

print(ranking(A))
```

I expect something like this (not exactly as this is the result of an approximation from a different program):

```
Matrix([[0.376637031250000], [0.138913750000000],
[0.197734375000000], [0.286714843750000]])
```

But the function is returning only this:

```
[]
```

**edit:**
I found a solution, if i use

```
from scipy.linalg import null_space
```

and then in the function

```
return null_space(np.array(x).astype("float64"))
```

output now is the following which is what i expected:

```
[[-0.70502501]
[-0.25856055]
[-0.3749128 ]
[-0.54362356]]
```

Why does scipy's `null_space()` work and not sympy's `.nullspace()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check the section of [`Zero Testing`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/matrices.html) from the Sympy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect a non trivial kernel?

The determinant of the matrix is not zero.

Scipy also shows trivial kernel

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import null_space

def ranking(A,m=0.1):
    A = sp.Matrix(A)
    shape = sp.shape(A)
    n = shape[0]
    S = []

    for i in range(n):
        S.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            S[i].append(1/n)

    S = sp.Matrix(S)
    google = (1-m)*A + m*S
    x = sp.Matrix(google-sp.eye(n))
    return x.nullspace()
   
A = [[0  , 0  , 1/2, 1  ],
     [1/3, 0  , 0  , 0  ],
     [1/3, 1/2, 0  , 0  ],
     [1/3, 1/2, 1/2, 0  ]]

print("Determinant", np.linalg.det(A))
print("scipy nullspace", null_space(A))

print(ranking(A, m=0.1))
```

Output:

```
Determinant -0.08333333333333333
scipy nullspace []
[]
```

Comment: A is a different matrix from x. I agree that null(A) would be the zero vector, but with x i expect a different result. Using matlab i get the following result of `null(x)`: (-0.7050, -0.2586, -0.3759, -0.5436)

Comment: Ok i found a solution with the scipy null_space().  `null_space(np.array(x).astype("float64"))` Do you know why this works and not sympys .nullspace() ?

Comment: sympy is not very common. Scipy is a lot more popular library. Happy my answer helped you to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is your matrix `x`:

```
In [32]: x
Out[32]: 
⎡-0.975  0.025   0.475   0.925 ⎤
⎢                              ⎥
⎢0.325   -0.975  0.025   0.025 ⎥
⎢                              ⎥
⎢0.325   0.475   -0.975  0.025 ⎥
⎢                              ⎥
⎣0.325   0.475   0.475   -0.975⎦
```

It is a matrix of floats because you are using floats e.g. `1/3` rather than exact rational numbers. In SymPy you should use `S(1)/3` or `Rational(1, 3)` to get exact rational numbers. In general a nullspace calculation needs to be done with exact rational numbers because it is a degenerate case:

```
In [33]: x.det()
Out[33]: -1.76693319568990e-16

In [34]: x.nullspace()
Out[34]: []
```

To do the calculation with exact rational numbers we can convert your matrix with SymPy's `nsimplify`:

```
In [35]: x.applyfunc(nsimplify)
Out[35]: 
⎡-39          19    37 ⎤
⎢────  1/40   ──    ── ⎥
⎢ 40          40    40 ⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎢ 13   -39             ⎥
⎢ ──   ────  1/40  1/40⎥
⎢ 40    40             ⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎢ 13    19   -39       ⎥
⎢ ──    ──   ────  1/40⎥
⎢ 40    40    40       ⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎢ 13    19    19   -39 ⎥
⎢ ──    ──    ──   ────⎥
⎣ 40    40    40    40 ⎦

In [36]: x.applyfunc(nsimplify).nullspace()
Out[36]: 
⎡⎡14179⎤⎤
⎢⎢─────⎥⎥
⎢⎢10933⎥⎥
⎢⎢     ⎥⎥
⎢⎢ 400 ⎥⎥
⎢⎢ ─── ⎥⎥
⎢⎢ 841 ⎥⎥
⎢⎢     ⎥⎥
⎢⎢ 20  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢ ──  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢ 29  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢     ⎥⎥
⎣⎣  1  ⎦⎦

In [37]: _[0].evalf()
Out[37]: 
⎡1.29689929571023 ⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎢0.475624256837099⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎢0.689655172413793⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎣       1.0       ⎦
```

This is not quite the result that you expected because SymPy chooses here to normalise so that the last element is 1 rather than giving a unit norm. This is because it means that the result can still be expressed exactly while using only rational numbers. If you want a unit length result then you can normalise this yourself:

```
In [41]: [v] = x.applyfunc(nsimplify).nullspace()

In [42]: v/v.norm()
Out[42]: 
⎡14179⋅√404466130⎤
⎢────────────────⎥
⎢   404466130    ⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎢ 520⋅√404466130 ⎥
⎢ ────────────── ⎥
⎢    40446613    ⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎢ 754⋅√404466130 ⎥
⎢ ────────────── ⎥
⎢    40446613    ⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎢10933⋅√404466130⎥
⎢────────────────⎥
⎣   404466130    ⎦

In [43]: (v/v.norm()).evalf()
Out[43]: 
⎡0.70502500885976 ⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎢0.258560550537468⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎢0.374912798279328⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎣0.543623557505026⎦
```

This is the result that you expected although different by a minus sign. The sign is still arbitrary even if we require unit norm though so this is equivalent.